# Using SQL to get the last item before n

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am not quite sure how to ask this so I will start off with an example.  Let's say I have a table in my database that looks like this:

```
id | time | event | pnumber
---------------------------
1  | 1200 | foo   | 23
2  | 1130 | bar   | 52
3  | 1045 | bat   | 13
...
n  | 0    | baz   | 7
```

Now say I wanted to get the last known pnumber after a certain time.  For example at time = 1135, it would have to go back and find the last known time in the table (1130) and then return that pnumber.  So for t = 1130, it would return pnumber = 52.  But as soon as the t = 1045 it would return pnumber = 13.  (Time counts down in this context from 1200 to 0).

Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT pnumber FROM table WHERE time = (SELECT time FROM table WHERE time <= '1135' ORDER BY time LIMIT 1)
```

Is there an easier way to do this?  Without using multiple statements.  I am using sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  You can condense that query by doing:

```
SELECT pnumber FROM table WHERE time >= 1135 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

No need to nest the select to get a specific time first, this should work.

EDIT: Got the inequality sign mixed around -- if you're looking for the first record AFTER a specific time, you'll want `time >= 1135` and order by time descending with a limit of one.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the second query? Could you do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 pnumber FROM table WHERE time  >= '1135' ORDER BY TIME DESC
```

Comment: Brain fart :P that's why.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused.  You are asking that 1135 would return the value for 1130, yet you are using greater than or equal to instead of less than.  If your example is what you are looking for, try this.

```
SELECT PNUMBER FROM TABLE WHERE TIME<=1135 ORDER BY TIME DESC LIMIT 1
```